# Class to automatically create Valve VDM files by timestamps

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project which should create VDM files. Here's a basic example:

```
demoactions
{
    "1"
    {
        factory "SkipAhead"
        name "skip"
        starttick "1"
        skiptotick "3623"
    }
    "2"
    {
        factory "PlayCommands"
        name "startrec"
        starttick "4123"
        commands "startrecording"
    }
    "3"
    {
        factory "PlayCommands"
        name "stoprec"
        starttick "4753"
        commands "stoprecording"
    }
    "4"
    {
        factory "PlayCommands"
        name "nextdem"
        starttick "4125"
        commands "playdemo demoName.dem"
    }
}
```

The main gist of this is the following:

"1":
The first thing we do is skip to a tick

"2": A few ticks later we issue the command "startrecording".
"3": After x amount of time we issue the command "stoprecording"

We repeat "2" and "3" with different ticks how many times we need.
At the end we optionally issue the command "playdemo".

To automatically generate such files I wrote the following class:

```
class EventVDM {
            constructor() {
                this.link;
                this.fileName;
                this.events = [];
                this.recordingMultipliers= []
            }
            set setLink(fileName) {
                this.link = fileName;
            }
            addEvent(tick,recordingMultiplier = 0) {
                this.events.push(tick)
                this.recordingMultipliers.push(recordingMultiplier)
            }
            toString() {
                this.events.sort((a, b) => a - b) //Make sure the ticks are in order
                let vdmString = "demoactions\n {\n"
                let indexAdjust = 0; //If we have two ticks that are too close to each other this increments e.g (100,110)
                let count = 2; //The number we write in quotation marks  
                let skipBuffer = 500; //skips 500 ticks before the record statement is issued
                let stopRecordBuffer = parseInt($("#recordDuration")[0].value) * 66 //The user can specify a custom value default is 5(seconds) *66
                let startRecordBuffer = parseInt($("#prerecordDuration")[0].value) *66//The user can specify a custom value default is 5(seconds) *66
                for (let tickIndexString in this.events) {
                    let tickIndex = parseInt(tickIndexString)
                    if (indexAdjust + tickIndex < this.events.length) { //Make sure we don't try to access an element out of range
                        let tick = this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust]
                        if (tickIndex == 0) { //If it's the very first index skip to first tick ("1")
                            vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count - 1, 1, tick, skipBuffer)
                        }
                        vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "startrec", tick - startRecordBuffer, `commands "startrecording"`) //Initiate first record
                        count++;
                        
                        if (this.events[tickIndex +indexAdjust +1] > tick + stopRecordBuffer+(this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex]*66)) { //If we can safely skip to the next tick
                            vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "stoprec", tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), `commands "stoprecording"`)
                            count++;
                            vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count, tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), this.events[tickIndex +indexAdjust+ 1], skipBuffer)
                            count++;
                        }
                        else { //Otherwise 
                            indexAdjust++;
                            vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "stoprec", tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), `commands "stoprecording"`)
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (this.link != undefined) {
                    vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "nextdem", this.events[this.events.length - 1] + stopRecordBuffer + 300, `commands "playdemo ${this.link}"`)
                }
                vdmString += "}"
                return vdmString;

            }
            skipToTickBuilder(count, starttick, tick, skipBuffer) {
                if (tick - skipBuffer > 1) { 
                    return this.buildPart(count, "SkipAhead", "skip", starttick, `skiptotick ${tick - skipBuffer}`)
                }
                else {//This generates initial skip ahead
                    return this.buildPart(count, "SkipAhead", "skip", starttick, `skiptotick ${tick}`)
                }
            }
            buildPart(count, factory, name, starttick, arg) {
                let string = `\t"${count}"\n`
                string += "\t{\n"
                string += `\t\t factory "${factory}"\n`
                string += `\t\t name "${name}"\n`
                string += `\t\t starttick "${starttick}"\n`
                string += `\t\t ${arg}\n`
                string += "\t}\n"
                return string;
            }
        }
```

Basically you can use addEvent to add ticks to a list and it the toString() method to create the "file". To create the file we have above we'd the following:

```
let vdm = new EventVDM()
vdm.setfileName = "demoName.dem"
vdm.addEvent(4453) //300 tick difference because of the startRecordBuffer
vdm.toString()
```

I'm very much new to all of this so I'm wondering if what I've done is readable and understandable and also if there are any better ways to do things like this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Always [use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278652)** when possible if you're going to write in ES6+; only use `let` when you need to reassign a variable

**Consistent spacing** You have lines like: `[0].value) *66` `this.events[tickIndex +indexAdjust +1]` `stopRecordBuffer+(this.recordingMultipliers` Code is easiest to read when operators have a space between the operator and its operands. Consider using an IDE which properly formats code automatically (like VSCode), or [a linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops) that can detect such things and prompt you to fix it automatically.

**setLink?** You have a `setLink` setter. For it to be used, it'd look like: `vdm.setLink = 'foobar'`. That looks somewhat odd. How about making `setLink` a normal method instead, so you can do `vdm.setLink('foobar')`?

**String building** You might be able to improve the `buildPart` method. To start with, template literals can span multiple lines, which can be nicer than using lots of `string +=` and `\n` concatenation, eg:

```
const buildPart = (count, factory, name, starttick, arg) =>
`\t"${count}"
\t{
\t\t factory "${factory}"
\t\t name "${name}"
// etc
```

You could also use literal tab characters instead of `\t` to improve readability (but Stack Exchange's renderer doesn't work well with tabs).

Also, the VDM format looks very close to JSON. It may be possible to construct an object of objects instead:

```
{
  1: {
      factory: "SkipAhead",
      name: "skip",
      starttick: "1",
      skiptotick: "3623"
  },
  // ...
```

When you need to turn it into a string, use `JSON.stringify` [with a space argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), then use a simple regular expression to get the rest to line up with the required format as needed.

**Break early to avoid indentation hell** You have:

```
for (let tickIndexString in this.events) {
    let tickIndex = parseInt(tickIndexString)
    if (indexAdjust + tickIndex < this.events.length) { //Make sure we don't try to access an element out of range
        // a large block
    }
} // end of for loop
```

IMO, code is most readable when you try to cut down on the amount of indentation and `}`s in a row at the end of a section of logic. Consider instead something like:

```
for (let tickIndexString in this.events) {
    const tickIndex = parseInt(tickIndexString);
    const tick = this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust];
    if (!tick) {
        break;
    }
    // more code here
}
```

**Line length** You have (original indentation included):

```
                    vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count, tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1], skipBuffer)
```

Even on my reasonably large Full HD monitor, this line goes off the screen. If someone has to scroll horizontally to see all the code, that's a bad sign. Consider requiring a [maximum line length](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len). It doesn't have to be the (IMO) incredibly small 80 characters, but 187 is probably too much. Choose a number that can at least fit comfortably on the monitors of those who may need to read the code.

Scrolling isn't the only issue - there's quite a lot happening in that line. Don't be afraid to break something up into multiple lines if it makes it easier to understand, eg:

```
vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(
    count,
    tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66),
    this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1],
    skipBuffer
);
```

or put the arguments into variables first, to make the code more self-documenting:

```
const startTick = tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66);
const nextTick = this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1];
vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count, startTick, nextTick, skipBuffer);
```

**Semicolons** Sometimes you're using semicolons when proper at the end of statements. Sometimes you aren't. If you forget a semicolon, you may eventually run into a bug due to [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). Code style should be consistent; either use semicolons or don't. Unless you're an expert on ASI and can avoid those sorts of bugs on sight, I'd recommend using semicolons. Enforce your desired style with [with a linting rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi).

**Avoid repeating lines** You repeat the same *long* line twice, the one starting with `vdmString += this.buildPart`:

```
if (this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1] > tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66)) { //If we can safely skip to the next tick
    vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "stoprec", tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), `commands "stoprecording"`)
    count++;
    vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count, tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1], skipBuffer)
    count++;
}
else { //Otherwise 
    indexAdjust++;
    vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "stoprec", tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66), `commands "stoprecording"`)
    count++;
}
```

Whenever you see a not-insignificant amount of code being repeated, it's a good time to take a step back and consider if it can be made more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), to make the code more concise and structured so that if a change needs to occur in the future, you can change only *one* section, rather than two or more at the same time. The above can be turned into:

```
const startTick = tick + stopRecordBuffer + (this.recordingMultipliers[tickIndex] * 66);
vdmString += this.buildPart(count, "PlayCommands", "stoprec", startTick, `commands "stoprecording"`)
const nextTick = this.events[tickIndex + indexAdjust + 1];
if (nextTick > startTick) { //If we can safely skip to the next tick
    count++;
    vdmString += this.skipToTickBuilder(count, startTick, nextTick, skipBuffer);
} else {
    indexAdjust++;
}
count++;
```

Comment: Code formatting:  an empty line above and below all conditional statement blocks; `if`, `while`, `for`, et cetera. From years of reading code, I love this.